# What is the covariance between estimated coefficient of a regression model?

Tags: regression, self-study, covariance, matrix, regression-coefficients

> Consider the simple linear regression model:
>   \begin{align}
> Y_i       &= \beta_1 + \beta_2X_i + u_i  \\
> \hat{Y}_i &= b_1 + b_2X_i
> \end{align}
>   (a) Show that the regression line always passes through the point $(\bar X, \bar Y)$.  What does this imply about the covariance between $b_1$ and $b_2$?

I have been reading a lot about covariance matrix, but how does it relate to X bar and Y bar? The only time when cov appears is in b2 = cov(x,y) / var (x,y) The regression that passes through X bar Y bar can be shown via RSS.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).  Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: The only time when cov appears is in b2 = cov(x,y) / var (x,y)

The regression that passes through Xbar Ybar can be shown via RSS

Comment: Please explain terms in two models and covariance between b1 and b2  ?